# Match up data in 2 sheets and change data in another cell if they match

Tags: vba, excel, match, vlookup

Sheet 1

```
  E           -          K     -  L        -       M         -      BC
1 -Product Code/SKU -Price  -Cost Price -Retail Price   -Product UPC/EAN
2 -0100040          -10.79  -6.85       -11.99          -765462008109
3 -0100529          -9.99   -6.00       -8.99           -835787000758
```

Sheet 2

```
   A        -    B         -     C                      -D      -E      -F
1 -Brand        -UNFI Product # -Product Name           -Retail -Cost   -LP Price
2 -Natralia     -0100529        -Natralia Dry Skin Wash -9.99   -6.00   -8.99
3 -Natralia     -0100701        -Natralia Dry Skin Lot  -9.99   -6.00   -8.99
4 -Head Products-0103432        -Head Organics Clearly  -13.59  -6.49   -12.19
```

In the above table I need to match sheet 1 E:E with B:B on sheet 2 and if those match I need (ONLY the ones that match) K:K to change to what is in F:F of sheet 2, L:L to change to E:E and K:K to F:F. This is same for about 15,000 lines/products in sheet one new price updates for about 4,000 products are on sheet two.

Comment: What have you tried? [See this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: nothing really, I have no clue how to do it but I am sure there has to be a way lol

Comment: @BillN. You should post that as the answer. Also, if you use the ` key around formulas and code, it will format them the correct way.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Sorry, I'm to self important to read the helpful yellow box below the typing area.

Answer (score 0):

Per PermaNoob's suggestion, I am reposting my comment as an answer. Upvote his comment if you like the answer.

You can easily do this with a VLOOKUP. There's no need to use VBA. Just create two extra columns in Sheet 1 and fill the second row of each column with the following into the first column: 
`=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(E2,'sheet 2'!B:B,1,FALSE)), K2, VLOOKUP(E2,'sheet 2'!B:F,5,FALSE))`

... and the second row of the second column should read:

`=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(E2,'sheet 2'!B:B,1,FALSE)), L2, VLOOKUP(E2,'sheet 2'!B:E,4,FALSE))`

Drag that down and that's your new data; Keep in mind you'll need to change the name of "sheet 2" to whatever you have that second sheet called.